# $(this) not working on dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending input fields to a div on a action. When i try to access the value inside the input field using `$(this).val()` i am just getting empty values.

```
$('#div').append('<td class = "fund-amount"><input type="number" class="custom-amount" id='+value.response_code+' placeholder="Rs."></td>');
```

Depending upon the action there can be any number of input field appended to the div. I want to get the values entered on each field. when i tried to to get the value using this approach below, it didn't work out. But when i got the dynamically created id value and used in the place of `$(this)` it worked

```
 $(document).keyup('.custom-amount',function(){
     console.log($(this).val()); //just logging empty
     console.log($(this).attr('id')); //Logged undefined

  })
```

but this one works

```
 $(document).keyup('#100520',function(){
     console.log($('#100520').val());//works
     console.log($('#100520').val());//works
 });
```

Is there anything wrong with my approach ?

Comment: This is more of a side comment, but you really shouldn't overloading the `document` with your event handling, instead bind it to a closer ancestor element.

Comment: Another side comment. Appending table cells to a div is... not very well thought out markup.

Comment: Create a [mcve] that reproduces issue

Comment: just at top of my  head, '.custom-amount' might be returning an array with one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('key-up','.custom-amount',function(){
     console.log($(this).val()); //just logging empty
     console.log($(this).attr('id')); //Logged undefined

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.custom-amount', function(){
   console.log($(this).val()); 
   console.log($(this).attr('id'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```js
$('#div').append('<td class = "fund-amount"><input type="number" class="custom-amount" id='+100520+' placeholder="Rs."></td>');

$('.custom-amount').keyup(function() {
  console.log($(this).val()); // value
  console.log($(this).attr('id')); // id
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id= "div">
</div>
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/cm4rLvq1/

Answer (score 0):

Calling `$(this)` in your handler is working as expected. Because you are handling events like this `$(document).keyup` your handler is invoked on the `document` element and not on the element itself, and therefor `this` refers to the `document`.

But when you supply event arg object to your handler function, you can use its property `target` which will refer to the element which triggered the event, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("keyup", ".custom-amount",function(e){
    console.log($(e.target).val()); 
    console.log($(e.target).attr('id')); 
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="custom-amount" id="some-id" />
```